# Windows Phone 8 App Store Submission

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

While trying to submit a Windows Phone 8 app to the Windows Store, I got the following error.

1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_malloc_dbg() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:memcpy() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:setvbuf() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll:GetModuleHandleW() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseChangedStateException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?FreeException@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:exp() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_cast_String_to_Object@__abi_details@@YAP$AAVObject@Platform@@P$AAVString@3@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0InvalidArgumentException@Platform@@Q$AAA@P$AAVString@1@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:wcstombs_s() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?_NewCollection@_AsyncTaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@SAPAV123@PAV_CancellationTokenState@23@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?UninitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAXH@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_snprintf() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:wcscpy_s() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:strcpy() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?GetActivationFactoryByPCWSTR@@YAJPAXAAVGuid@Platform@@PAPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:wcscmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_onexit() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_CrtDbgReportW() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:fmod() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0ValueType@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_initterm() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidCastException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?Allocate@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXI@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:isspace() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_wsplitpath_s() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:toupper() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseWrongThreadException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:__dllonexit() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll:GetModuleHandleW() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:??1_Lockit@std@@QAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_initterm_e() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseWrongThreadException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:??0_Container_base12@std@@QAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_cast_Object_to_String@__abi_details@@YAP$AAVString@Platform@@_NP$AAVObject@3@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?what@exception@std@@UBAPBDXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:calloc() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll:GetModuleFileNameW() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:strchr() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseChangedStateException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?GetIidsFn@@YAJHPAKPBU__s_GUID@@PAPAVGuid@Platform@@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:fabs() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:_Mtx_lock() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:clock() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:??2@YAPAXI@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseFailureException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_FailFast@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:mbstowcs() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0Enum@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:wcscmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?__ExceptionPtrCreate@@YAXPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:?_Throw_C_error@std@@YAXH@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_stricmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0Enum@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:__iob_func() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_calloc_dbg() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_strnicmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseNotImplementedException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_cast_Object_to_String@__abi_details@@YAP$AAVString@Platform@@_NP$AAVObject@3@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_CRT_RTC_INITW() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?_RegisterCallback@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@QAAXPAV_CancellationTokenRegistration@23@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:sqrt() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:memcpy() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:acos() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfMemoryException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?ReCreateFromException@Details@Platform@@YAJP$AAVException@2@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_CrtSetCheckCount() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException@@YAXJ@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfBoundsException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:mbstowcs_s() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseOperationCanceledException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseClassNotRegisteredException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:wcscpy_s() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?GetIidsFn@@YAJHPAKPBU__s_GUID@@PAPAVGuid@Platform@@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:fopen() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:__CppXcptFilter() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:strlen() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?EventSourceGetTargetArrayEvent@Details@Platform@@YAPAXPAXI@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:free() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_unlock() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:isxdigit() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?terminate@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_amsg_exit() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:??0_Lockit@std@@QAA@H@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:??_U@YAPAXI@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:setjmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_invalid_parameter() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:strncpy() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_unlock() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseOperationCanceledException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidCastException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:_Mtx_init() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?_Cancel@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@QAAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:__CxxFrameHandler3() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfBoundsException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:printf() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_invalid_parameter() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:longjmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:fprintf() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_CrtSetCheckCount() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0NotImplementedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:__CxxFrameHandler3() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:memcmp() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCP110D.dll:_Mtx_lock() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_wmakepath_s() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?__abi_WinRTraiseObjectDisposedException@@YAXXZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?TerminateModule@Details@Platform@@YA_NPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0Exception@Platform@@Q$AAA@HP$AAVString@1@@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?GetIBoxArrayVtable@Details@Platform@@YAPAXPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:cos() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:?__ExceptionPtrCurrentException@@YAXPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_free_dbg() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:??_V@YAXPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:strcpy() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?ReCreateException@Exception@Platform@@SAP$AAV12@H@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?InitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAJH@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:_amsg_exit() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:__clean_type_info_names_internal() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:memset() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0Delegate@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:?EventSourceUninitialize@Details@Platform@@YAXPAPAX@Z() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API MSVCR110D.dll:floor() isn’t allowed in assembly PjsuaWP.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.
1028: The native API vccorlib110d.DLL:??0DisconnectedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ() isn’t allowed in assembly PhoneVoIPApp.BackEnd.dll. Update it and then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short.  Never build in Debug for App store submissions.  You must build in Release.  This includes all project references and 3rd party dlls as well.